# AJAX not finding PHP files in Angular

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ajax, gruntjs

I'm using a pre-made Grunt to deploy a website locally, i.e.: I was given this and told "make work". I've never used Yeoman, I don't have it installed, and I know nothing about it.

I'm trying to create a login system for it, and as part of that I need to access PHP files for server-side processing and database access. Except I can't do that.

I'm using JQuery's AJAX on Google Chrome, and AngularJS. The directory tree is as follows:
[image: Tree directory including the php file]

Here is the AJAX query:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "scripts/models/login.php",
    data: {
        "user" : username,
        "pass" : password,
        "keep" : keepLogin
    },
    method: "POST",
    success: function(response) {
        console.log("succ");
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(response) {
        console.log("fucc");
    }
});
```

If I go to localhost:port/robots.txt it displays that fine, and AJAX can access it fine too. However it cannot access the php file or even index.html for that matter.

Angular handles URL handling, i.e.: you can't access the files directly, so I'm suspecting the problem is there. Example:

```
$routeProvider
.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'main'
})
```

Any ideas? I'm stuck on practically the first step here. :(

Comment: `it cannot access the php file or even index.html` what's happening? Is it 404-ing or are you getting a different error?

Comment: try using $http service

Comment: @Ankh Indeed, 404. Something along the lines of "localhost:9000/scripts/models/login.php - 404"

Comment: @swordf1zh Didn't help.

Comment: @Ankh "POST http://localhost:port/scripts/models/login.php 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: Have you tried moving the PHP file to the same location as `robots.txt`?

Comment: @Ankh Ok, found something: GET works, POST doesn't. How?

Comment: what server are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There needs to be an actual server in place: a Grunt deployer is not a server.